# Core Data delay when switching NSPersistentStore files

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm developing an app with Core Data that periodically downloads all the data from a webservice. Since the download can fail or be cancelled by the user, I want to be able to roll back to the previous state. I tried undoing the `NSManagedObjectContext`, but that seemed a bit slow (I have tens of thousands of entities). What I'm doing right now is making a backup of the persistent store file, download the data, and, if the download fails, replace the store file with the backup. This seems to work correctly, except there seems to be a delay after I can fetch entities from the store: if after the download I go immediately to a `UITableView` that uses an `NSFetchedResultsController`, I find it empty. If I wait some seconds, everything is ok.

So my question is: has anyone had this kind of delays too? Is there something that can be done to avoid this problem, something that forces everything to be ready, even if it blocks the thread?

Comment: The problem was that the restore took some time to get called after tapping the "cancel" button, that's why the entities were not being shown.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this setup but I think the delay you are seeing is probably caused by Core Data having to clear all it's caching. Core Data uses If you use a cache with the fetched results controller it will have to test and then delete it's existing cache.

I think the best thing to do is to tear down you Core Data stack and reboot it from scratch. That includes recreating a fresh fetched results controller.

Comment: I am recreating the fetched results controller, but still getting the delay. In fact, since the fetched results controller receives contextDidSave notifications, changing stores leaves managed objects pointing to a non existant store.

But I'll try reseting the whole stack (store coordinator, model, managed context) and see how it goes.

Comment: Well, it was another problem, replying on the original question.